# What is the difference between "sort -u" and "sort | uniq"?

Tags: bash, sort, uniq

Everywhere I see someone needing to get a sorted, unique list, they always pipe to `sort | uniq`. I've never seen any examples where someone uses `sort -u` instead. Why not? What's the difference, and why is it better to use uniq than the unique flag to sort?

Comment: http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/sort-vs-uniq.html

Answer (score 167, accepted):

`sort | uniq` existed before `sort -u`, and is compatible with a wider range of systems, although almost all modern systems do support `-u` -- it's POSIX. It's mostly a throwback to the days when `sort -u` didn't exist (and people don't tend to change their methods if the way that they know continues to work, just look at `ifconfig` vs. `ip` adoption).

The two were likely merged because removing duplicates within a file requires sorting (at least, in the standard case), and is an extremely common use case of sort. It is also faster internally as a result of being able to do both operations at the same time (and due to the fact that it doesn't require IPC ([Inter-process communication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))) between `uniq` and `sort`). Especially if the file is big, `sort -u` will likely use fewer intermediate files to sort the data.

On my system I consistently get results like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/shm/file bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 8.95208 s, 11.7 MB/s
$ time sort -u /dev/shm/file >/dev/null

real        0m0.500s
user        0m0.767s
sys         0m0.167s
$ time sort /dev/shm/file | uniq >/dev/null

real        0m0.772s
user        0m1.137s
sys         0m0.273s
```

It also doesn't mask the return code of `sort`, which may be important (in modern shells there are ways to get this, for example, `bash`'s `$PIPESTATUS` array, but this wasn't always true).

Comment: I tend to use `sort | uniq` because 9 times out of 10, I'm actually piping to `uniq -c`.

Comment: Note that `sort -u` was part of 7th Edition UNIX, circa 1979.  Versions of `sort` without support for `-u` are truly archaic — or were written without attention to the de facto standard before POSIX's de jure standard.  See also Stack Overflow [Sort & uniq in Linux shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382936/sort-uniq-in-linux-shell) from 2010.

Comment: +1 because of `ip`. It's 2016 and this post in 2013, but I only know about `ip` command now.

Comment: +1 for "9 times out 10 I'm actually piping to `uniq -c` " (and maybe piping once more to `sort -nr | head` ). I was wondering what is the equivalent to `sort | uniq` in Vim when I found out that Vim has `:sort u` command. And TIL `sort -u` exists as well.

Comment: Note that there is a difference when using `sort -n | uniq` vs. `sort -n -u`. For example trailing and leading whitespaces will be seen as duplicates by `sort -n -u` but not by the former! `echo -e 'test   \n  test' | sort -n -u` returns `test`, but `echo -e 'test   \n  test' | sort -n | uniq` returns both lines.

Comment: Another problem with `sort -n -u` becomes apparent with this `echo -e '14a-foo\n14b-bar\n15' | sort -n -u` ... i.e. the `14b-bar` will be deleted! Not sure if this is a bug or not, though. This does not happen with with `sort -n | uniq`. Imo you should never use `sort -n -u`, it only leads to trouble.

Comment: Is `ifconfig` an alias to `ip`?

Comment: @stephanmg `$ pacman -Qo ifconfig` ->
"/usr/bin/ifconfig is owned by net-tools 2.10-1"; `$ pacman -Qo ip` -> "/usr/bin/ip is owned by iproute2 5.10.0-2".

Answer (score 60):

With POSIX compliant `sort`s and `uniq`s (GNU `uniq` is currently not compliant in that regard), [there's a difference](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/10517/focus=10524) in that `sort` uses the locale's collating algorithm to compare strings (will typically use `strcoll()` to compare strings) while `uniq` checks for byte-value identity (will typically use `strcmp()`)¹.

That matters for at least two reasons.

- In some locales, especially on GNU systems, there are different characters that sort the same. For instance, in the en_US.UTF-8 locale on a GNU system, all the ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩... characters² and many others sort the same because their sort order is not defined. The 0123456789 arabic digits sort the same as their [Eastern Arabic Indic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) counterparts (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩).

  For `sort -u`, ① sorts the same as ② and 0123 the same as ٠١٢٣  so `sort -u` would retain only one of each, while for `uniq` (not GNU `uniq` which uses `strcoll()` (except with `-f`)), ① is different from ② and 0123 different from ٠١٢٣, so `uniq` would consider all 4 unique.
- `strcoll` can only compare strings of valid characters (the behaviour is undefined as per POSIX when the input has sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters) while `strcmp()` doesn't care about characters since it only does byte-to-byte comparison. So that's another reason why `sort -u` may not give you all the unique lines if some of them don't form valid text. `sort|uniq`, while still unspecified on non-text input, in practice is more likely to give you unique lines for that reason.

Beside those subtleties, one thing that hasn't been noted so far is that `uniq` compares whole line lexically, while `sort`'s `-u` compares based on the sort specification given on the command line.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'a b' 'a c' | sort -uk 1,1
a b
$ printf '%s\n' 'a b' 'a c' | sort -k 1,1 | uniq
a b
a c

$ printf '%s\n' 0 -0 +0 00 '' | sort -n | uniq
0
-0
+0
00

$ printf '%s\n' 0 -0 +0 00 '' | sort -nu
0
```

---

<sup>¹ Prior versions of the POSIX spec were causing confusion however by listing the `LC_COLLATE` variable as one affecting `uniq`, that was removed in the 2018 edition and the behaviour clarified following that discussion mentioned above. See [the corresponding Austin group bug](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=963)</sup>

<sup>² **2019 edit**. Those have since been fixed, but [over 95% of Unicode code points still have an undefined order as of version 2.30 of the GNU libc](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-12/msg00098.html). You can test with  instead for instance in newer versions</sup>

Answer (score 56):

One difference is that `uniq` has a number of useful additional options, such as skipping fields for comparison and counting the number of repetitions of a value. `sort`'s `-u` flag only implements the functionality of the unadorned `uniq` command.

Comment: +0.49 for a useful answer, but I would phrase it something like "The output of `sort -u` can't be passed to `uniq` to use some of the latter's useful options, such as skipping fields for comparison and counting the number of repetitions."

Comment: +1 to offset the naysayers because "there's no way to do this directly from sort" _does_ answer the question...

Comment: Landed here because I want `uniq -u` (_only_ unique rows) behaviour and I can't seem to get it from sort (also want GNU `uniq -w` and can't get that from BSD).  So yes, this answer is important.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use `sort | uniq` because when I try to use the `-u` (eliminate duplicates) option to remove duplicates involving mixed case strings, it is not that easy to understand the result.

Note: before you can run the examples below, you need to simulate the standard C collating sequence by doing the following:

```
LC_ALL=C
export LC_ALL
```

For example, if I want to sort a file and remove duplicates, while at the same time, keeping the different cases of strings distinct.

```
$ cat short      #file to sort
Pear
Pear
apple
pear
Apple

$ sort short     #normal sort (in normal C collating sequence)
Apple            #the lower case words are at the end
Pear
Pear
apple
pear

$ sort -f short  #correctly sorts ignoring the C collating order
Apple            #but duplicates are still there
apple
Pear
Pear
pear

$ sort -fu short #By adding the -u option to remove duplicates it is 
apple            #difficult to ascertain the logic that sort uses to remove
Pear             #duplicates(i.e., why did it remove pear instead of Pear?)
```

This confusion is solved by not using the `-u` option to remove duplicates. Using `uniq` is more predictable. The below first sorts and ignores the case and then passes it to `uniq` to remove the duplicates.

```
$ sort -f short | uniq
Apple
apple
Pear
pear
```

Comment: `-u` option of `sort` outputs the **first** of an equal run (see man page). Thus `sort -fu` picks up the first occurence of every case-insensitive unique line. The logic that `sort` uses to remove duplicates is predictable.

Answer (score 6):

Another difference I found out today is when sorting based on a delimeter where `sort -u` applies the unique flag only on the column that you sort with.

```
$ cat input.csv
3,World,1
1,Hello,1
2,Hello,1

$ cat input.csv | sort -t',' -k2 -u
1,Hello,1
3,World,1

$ cat input.csv | sort -t',' -k2 | uniq
1,Hello,1
2,Hello,1
3,World,1
```

Comment: This is mentioned in an answer from Stéphane Chazelas but I like your example so +1

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @roaima, it wasn't very clear in that answer