# Sort -u without sorting but with better uniqueness?

Tags: bash, sort, uniq

I don't want to sort my file, just filter out duplicate lines, maintaining the original ordering.  Is there a way to use sort's unique function without it's sort function (something like `cat -u` would give if it existed)? Just using `uniq` without `sort` does nothing worthwhile, because `uniq` only looks at adjacent lines, so a file has to be sorted first.

Also, incidentally, what in hell is the difference between `uniq` and `uniq --unique`?  Here are commands on a random file from pastebin:

```
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | wc -l
350
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort -u | wc -l
287
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort | uniq | wc -l
287
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort | uniq -u | wc -l
258
```

In summary:

1. How do I filter duplicates greedily without sorting?
2. How is `uniq` not unique enough that there is also `uniq --unique`?

p.s.  This question looks like a duplicate of the following q's, but it isn't:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287871/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-uniq
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382936/sort-uniq-in-linux-shell
- [What is the difference between "sort -u" and "sort | uniq"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76049/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-sort-uniq)

Comment: Don't use `sort` or `uniq` at all. And "How is uniq not unique enough that there is also uniq --unique?" really should be a separate question.

Comment: The solution on the duplicate page has an in-bash solution using awk. Suits me.  

As for the separate question, I just posted it here:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210528/how-is-uniq-not-unique-enough-that-there-is-also-uniq-unique

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl and a hash.

Something like:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my %seen; 

 while ( <> ) { 
     print unless $seen{$_}++; 
 }
```

I think this'd one-liner-ify as:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' data.txt
```

(Or cat data into it).

This works on getting unique whole lines - you can also use split or regular expressions to just compare subsets.

E.g.

```
while ( <> ) { 
    my @fields = split ( ";" ); 
    print unless $seen{$fields[4]}++; 
}
```

Will split the line into fields based on `;`, and just compare the 5th (first is zero in the array).