# How is uniq not unique enough that there is also uniq --unique?

Tags: uniq

Here are commands on a random file from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/):

```
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | wc -l
350
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort -u | wc -l
287
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort | uniq | wc -l
287
wget -qO - http://pastebin.com/0cSPs9LR | sort | uniq -u | wc -l
258
```

The man pages are not clear on what the `-u` flag is doing.  Any advice?

Comment: Try sort | uniq -d | wc -l and you might spot the difference. :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`uniq` with `-u` skips any lines that have duplicates. Thus:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 1 1 2 3 | uniq
1
2
3
$ printf "%s\n" 1 1 2 3 | uniq -u
2
3
```

Usually, `uniq` prints lines at most once (assuming sorted input). This option actually prints lines which are truly *unique* (having not appeared again).

Comment: That is, `uniq` could be called `distinct`, since it prints all distinct lines, whereas `uniq -u` prints all unique lines.

Comment: It's not *truly unique* with GNU `uniq` in some locale.

Comment: I must have read the accepted answer a number of times, but it didn't sink in. Your example and paragraph after it make it very clear (and going back and re-reading the accepted answer, I get that too) :)

Answer (score 47):

### Short version:

- `uniq`, without `-u`, makes every line **of the output** unique.
- `uniq -u` only prints every unique line **from the input**.

### Slightly longer version:

`uniq` is for dealing with files that have lines duplicated, and only when those lines appear successively in the input. So, for its purposes, a *unique* line is one that is not duplicated immediately.

(`uniq` has a very limited short-term memory; it will never remember whether a line appeared earlier in the input, unless it was the immediately previous line -- this is why `uniq` is very often paired with `sort`.)

When it encounters a run of duplicate lines, `uniq`, without the `-u` arg, prints **one** copy of that line. (It makes every line of the output *unique*).

With the `-u` argument, it prints **zero** copies of that line -- runs of duplicates just get omitted from the output.

Comment: I really wish there was an option to not require sorting. But it would require keeping the whole file in memory (or doing lots of bookkeeping with hashes and offsets if the source is a normal file)

Comment: @Random832: and it would require deciding which of the dupes to keep (first, last, something else, configurable), and that decision would affect the algorithm globally. Hassle.

Comment: @Random832: if it's just about the number of characters to type, you can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`.

Comment: @oliver I've occasionally wanted an ability to keep the first instance of any line without rearranging them, and written scripts to do so.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's *already* a decision that needs to be made, isn't it? Can't two lines compare as equal without actually being identical, for example if a Unicode file is not normalised and two equal lines use different normalisation forms?

Comment: @hvd: if your version of `uniq` does normalisation and collation, yes. But even then it's only a local consideration -- you know where in the sorted output the line will appear, and just have to select which of several adjacent lines to keep. If the input isn't sorted then the decision affects the whole operation of uniqifying, for example if you're going to keep the last duplicate then you can't output anything until you've read the last line of the input...

Comment: @SteveJessop That's a very good point, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 18):

[uniq POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html#tag_20_144_04) described it clearly:

```
-u
    Suppress the writing of lines that are repeated in the input.
```

`-u` option make `uniq` not to print repeated lines.

Most `uniq` implementations used bytes comparison, while GNU `uniq` used collation order to filter duplicated lines. So it can produce wrong result in some locales, example in `en_US.UTF-8` locale:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2460' '\U2461' | uniq
①
```

and `-u` gave you no lines:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2460' '\U2461' | uniq -u
<blank>
```

So you should set locale to `C` to get bytes comparison:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2460' '\U2461' | LC_ALL=C uniq
①
②
```

Comment: Note that what is _wrong_ here is not as much `uniq` (though apparently the intent of POSIX was that it should do byte comparison instead of strcoll() comparison as in `sort -u`) as those locales that erroneously have ① sorting the same as ②. At least GNU `uniq` is consistent with `sort -u`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - where in the spec is that made apparent?

Comment: About `uniq` required to do memcmp/strcmp as opposed to strcoll, that is not very apparent to me but [that was to Geoff](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/10517/focus=10524). About the GNU locales having ① sorting the same as ②, that's clearly a bug as there's no reason why they should sort the same. That's allowed by POSIX but [there's some change coming](http://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=938).

Answer (score 12):

normal:

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n'
a
b
a
b
c
c
c
```

uniq : no two subsequent repeating lines

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq
a
b
a
b
c
```

sorted

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

sort -u : no two repeating lines

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
a
b
c
```

sort / uniq: all distinct

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq
a
b
c
```

counts distinct occurrences

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
2 a
2 b
3 c
```

only lines which are not repeated (not sorted first)

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -u
a
b
a
b
```

only lines which are not repeated (after sorting)

```
echo "a b a b c c c Z" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
Z
```

uniq -d : only print duplicate lines, one for each group

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -d
c
```

.. counted

```
echo "a b a b c c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -dc
3 c
```

Comment: nice clear examples :)