# Using grep and looking for unique occurrences

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a text file of this type, and I would look for any lines containing the string `Validating Classification` and then obtain uniquely the reported errors. I do not know the types of possible errors.

Input file:

```
201600415 10:40 Error Validating Classification: error1
201600415 10:41 Error Validating Classification: error1
201600415 10:42 Error Validating Classification: error2
201600415 10:43 Error Validating Classification: error3
201600415 10:44 Error Validating Classification: error3
```

Output file

```
201600415 10:40 Error Validating Classification: error1
201600415 10:42 Error Validating Classification: error2
201600415 10:43 Error Validating Classification: error3
```

Can I achieve this using grep, pipes and other commands?

Comment: using `grep .... | sort --unique`

Comment: I vote for reopening this question. The one marked as duplicate is different because it it is not about grep. In case you are using git, the command `git grep -h  <pattern> | sort --unique` will give unique occurrences of grep matches.

Answer (score 95):

You will need to discard the timestamps, but 'grep' and 'sort --unique' together can do it for you.

```
grep --only-matching 'Validating Classification.*' | sort --unique
```

So `grep -o` will only show the parts of the line that match your regex (which is why you need to include the `.*` to include everything *after* the "Validating Classification" match). Then once you have just the list of errors, you can use [`sort -u`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76049/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-sort-uniq) to get just the unique list of errors.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this command assuming your data in in the file test

```
uniq -f 2 <test
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with awk

```
awk -F: '{ if (!a[$3]++ ) print ;}' file
```

- `-F:` use : as separator
- `$3` is pattern after `:`
- `!a[$3]++` ensure being true only on first occurence