# Check all lines of a file are unique

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file containing lines like this:

```
This is a thread  139737522087680
This is a thread  139737513694976
This is a thread  139737505302272
This is a thread  139737312270080
.
.
.
This is a thread  139737203164928
This is a thread  139737194772224
This is a thread  139737186379520
```

How can I be sure of the uniqueness of every line?

**NOTE:** The goal is to test the file, not to modify it if duplicate lines are present.

Comment: Linking in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76049/117549

Comment: Do you want to check if all lines are unique, or do you want to remove any duplicates?

Comment: @8bittree - wish to just be sure uniqueness

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
[ "$(wc -l < input)" -eq "$(sort -u input | wc -l)" ] && echo all unique
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have said, except with `uniq` instead of `sort -u`

Comment: If the input is not already sorted, `uniq` would be a big mistake; it only deduplicates adjacent lines!

Comment: If one is interested in the culprits, a `sort <file> | uniq -d` would print the duplicates.

Answer (score 25):

Awk solution:

```sh
awk 'a[$0]++{print "dupes"; exit(1)}' file && echo "no dupes"
```

Comment: +1 The accepted answer reads through the whole file twice, while this stops as soon as it encounters a duplicate line in one read. This will also work with piped input, while the other needs files it can re-read.

Comment: Couldn't you shove the `echo` into `END`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, it doesn't work (at least in GNU `awk`). Code in `END` is executed on the way out even when `exit()` is called

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There's really no point in the echo. Doing `&& echo` or `|| echo` is a convention in answers to indicate that a command does the right thing with the exit status code. The important thing is the `exit(1)`. Ideally, you'd use this like `if has_only_unique_lines file; then ...`, not `if [[ $(has_only_unique_lines file) = "no dupes" ]]; then ...`, that'd be silly.

Comment: Where other answers reads the file twice to save memory, this will read the whole file into memory, if there are no dupes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You can, if you set a flag when you find a dupe and switch what you output in `END` according to this.

Comment: @Kusalananda While this will read the whole file into memory when there are no dupes, using `sort` will too, regardless of whether there are dupes or not, right? How is that saving memory?

Comment: @JoL sorting an arbitrary sized file is done in chunks. When all chunks are individually sorted, they are merge-sorted to create the result.

Comment: @Kusalananda How does that relate to the reads, though? It still has to read all chunks into memory before outputting anything in case the last line should go first. I would guess that for piped input that's larger than available memory, sort might save it to a file and work with offset references, re-reading the file multiple times, but for anything smaller, I'd think it would opt for keeping it in memory.

Comment: @JoL GNU `sort` implements this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Answer (score 24):

Using `sort`/`uniq`:

```
sort input.txt | uniq
```

To check only for duplicate lines use the `-d` option for uniq.  This will show only lines that are duplicate, if none it will show nothing:

```
sort input.txt | uniq -d
```

Comment: This is my goto.  Not sure what the other, higher-voted answers offer that this one doesn't.

Comment: It's good alternative to remove duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. He wants to know *if* there are duplicates, not remove them.

Comment: @Barmar: While it does seem that way the question is still unclear.  As well as OPs comment attempting to clarify it.

Comment: There's a pending edit that adds more clarification.

Comment: It says "The goal is to test the file, not to modify the file if duplicate lines are present."

Comment: Clarification was added by a user other than OP.  OP says he wants to _ensure_ the file is unique.  Ensuring it's unique means removing duplicates.

Comment: @Jesse_b - Yeah this question has turned into a mess, IMO. Now we have a thrash of answers which drives me nuts 8--). The OP didn't make the edit, someone else did, I just approved it but it seems the consensus of what the OP was asking is what's there. I should've  just closed this as unclear to begin w/ and pushed it back on the OP.

Answer (score 6):

#### TLDR

The original question was unclear, and read that the OP simply wanted a unique version of the contents of a file. That's shown below. In the since updated form of the question, the OP is now stating that he/she simply wants to know if the contents of the file is unique or not.

---

### Test if file's contents is unique or not

You can simply use `sort` to verify if a file is unique or contains duplicates like so:

```
$ sort -uC input.txt && echo "unique" || echo "duplicates"
```

#### Example

Say I have these two files:

*duplicate sample file*

```
$ cat dup_input.txt
This is a thread  139737522087680
This is a thread  139737513694976
This is a thread  139737505302272
This is a thread  139737312270080
This is a thread  139737203164928
This is a thread  139737194772224
This is a thread  139737186379520
```

*unique sample file*

```
$  cat uniq_input.txt
A
B
C
D
```

Now when we analyze these files we can tell if they're unique or contain duplicates:

*test duplicates file*

```
$ sort -uC dup_input.txt && echo "unique" || echo "duplicates"
duplicates
```

*test unique file*

```
$ sort -uC uniq_input.txt && echo "unique" || echo "duplicates"
unique
```

### Original question (unique contents of file)

Can be done with just `sort`:

```
$ sort -u input.txt
This is a thread  139737186379520
This is a thread  139737194772224
This is a thread  139737203164928
This is a thread  139737312270080
This is a thread  139737505302272
This is a thread  139737513694976
This is a thread  139737522087680
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually `sort` the file, then use `uniq` to count the number of duplicates, then I `sort` once more see the duplicates at the bottom of the list.

I added one duplicate to the examples you provided:

```
$ sort thread.file | uniq -c | sort
      1 This is a thread  139737186379520
      1 This is a thread  139737194772224
      1 This is a thread  139737203164928
      1 This is a thread  139737312270080
      1 This is a thread  139737513694976
      1 This is a thread  139737522087680
      2 This is a thread  139737505302272
```

Since I haven't read the man page for `uniq` in awhile, I took a quick look for any alternatives. The following eliminates the need for the second sort, if you just want to see duplicates:

```
$ sort thread.file | uniq -d
This is a thread  139737505302272
```

Comment: It's a good alternative indeed. #rez

Answer (score 2):

If there are no duplicates, all lines are unique:

```
[ "$(sort file | uniq -d)" ] && echo "some line(s) is(are) repeated"
```

Description:
Sort the file lines to make repeated lines consecutive (sort)
Extract all consecutive lines that are equal (uniq -d).
If there is any output of the command above (`[...]`), then (`&&`) print a message.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be complete without a Perl answer!

```
$ perl -ne 'print if ++$a{$_} == 2' yourfile
```

This will print each non-unique line once: so if it prints nothing, then the file has all unique lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cmp` and `sort` in `bash`:

```
cmp -s <( sort file ) <( sort -u file ) && echo 'All lines are unique'
```

or

```
if cmp -s <( sort file ) <( sort -u file )
then
    echo 'All lines are unique'
else
    echo 'At least one line is duplicated'
fi
```

This would sort the file twice though, just like the accepted answer.